# iFrame not showing on iOS device

Tags: html, ios, css, iframe

On  my website: daniell.info I have a iFrame at the bottom of the page, it shows on desktops and Android devices but not on iOS devices, is there any solution for this? I tried to make it responsive but it still does not show up on iOS devices:

HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<iframe src="http://www.daniellwijdenbosch.epizy.com/index.php" style="border:none;" scrolling="no" width="100%"></iframe>
```

CSS:

```
iframe {
    margin-top:5%;
    height: 90vh;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Android developer can't solve your problem. Don't add `android` tag, if the question is not supposed to be useful to ANdroid developers. Removing the tag.